# jQuery and JavaScript in Firefox 3 and IE7+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm learning developing in javascript and jQuery. I'm puzzled on why the firefox and IE are soo different in handling javascript and jquery functions.

Firefox seems to be doing exactly what I want it to do, when the IE is all over the place and quite often I can't find a reasonable explanation why certain event didn't fire off or variable didn't get set.

Is there anything in particular that I should avoid while developing for these browsers?

Thank you

Comment: This is not true. There are some JavaScript handling differences, and some non-standard events aren't implemented in all browsers, but jQuery is working very, very well across browsers. Please show some real life examples.

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong. Post some code that demonstrates the problem. It could even be css... As a side note, jQuery is very good at keeping cross-browser compatibility issues hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Really, you should avoid anything prorietary, or non-standardised. You are most likely to find this when using versions of IE, and for it to not work in Firefox rather than vice-versa.

That said, if you are using jQuery, then a lot of the cross browser concerns should be handled for you automatically. So I suspect the issues you are encountering are more related to your own code than anything else.

Can you post some samples so we can get a better idea of what might be the issue?